# How to play .m3u8 in video tag in windows phone using WinJS?

Tags: html5-video, winjs, mmppf

I have used Streaming Media and successfully played m3u8 URLs in windows Phone. But, now I am struggling with m3u8 in video tag using WinJS. Can I some how use those DLL's for playing M3U8 in html5 in Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

We are currently in the same boat; we have WinJS apps which require m3u8 video's to be played. The Streaming Media is written in C# and therefore does not work in WinJS.

I'm currently investigating to see if it's possible to write a 'wrapper', that is, create a Windows Runtime Library as a proxy between WinJS and C#. This, in basic, is working, however I'm not sure how to access the video-element of the C# video-player (if this is even possible at all...).

I used:

http://www.ronaldwidha.net/2012/05/10/winrt-calling-c-csharp-class-libraries-from-winjs-javascript/

as a starting point.

So any solution would be welcome!

**Update: as I suspected, it's not possible to use a C# DLL with a UI component (say, the player's view) to display in Javascript.**

See also: [Passing UI elements to and from Windows Runtime Component in different environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323208/passing-ui-elements-to-and-from-windows-runtime-component-in-different-environments)?

Comment: can we use Media Element Parsers ?